# Google OAuth2 Authentication fails (redirect_uri: Missing scheme)

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

I am having trouble with Oauth2 for the Google API.

This is the setup:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Web client 1');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$client->setAuthConfig(APPLICATION_PATH.'/Service/oauth2.json');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setRedirectUri('https://my.api-1.webmetry.de/analyticsauth');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('consent');

return $client->createAuthUrl();
```

With this redirect URI setting in my Google Console:

[image: Google Console Uri]

When I open the returned URL I get this error:

> Error 400: invalid_request
>
> Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing scheme: https%3A%2F%2Fmy.api-1.webmetry.de%2Fanalyticsauth

What is the issue here? The common mistakes like not including a full, absolute Uri seem to be not the case here?

Comment: Can you provide what library you are using for `$client = new Google_Client();`?

Comment: This one: ("google/apiclient": "^2.7") https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client